# Convert map object to numpy array in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In Python 2 I could do the following:

```
import numpy as np    
f = lambda x: x**2
seq = map(f, xrange(5))
seq = np.array(seq)
print seq
# prints: [ 0  1  4  9 16]
```

In Python 3 it does not work anymore:

```
import numpy as np    
f = lambda x: x**2
seq = map(f, range(5))
seq = np.array(seq)
print(seq)
# prints: <map object at 0x10341e310>
```

How do I get the old behaviour (converting the `map` results to `numpy` array)?

**Edit**: As @jonrsharpe pointed out in his answer this could be fixed if I converted `seq` to a list first:

```
seq = np.array(list(seq))
```

but I would prefer to avoid the extra call to `list`.

Comment: I was actually aware about the `list` solution, but I was asking about a direct one.

Comment: Without converting to `list` fist. I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 56):

One more alternative, other than the valid solutions @jonrsharpe already pointed out is to use [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> f = lambda x: x**2
>>> seq = map(f, range(5))
>>> np.fromiter(seq, dtype=np.int)
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
```

Comment: `fromiter`'s example is essentially this: `np.fromiter((x*x for x in range(5)),int)`.

Answer (score 15):

Although you refer to it as `seq`, the `map` object in Python 3 is **not** a *sequence* (it's an *iterator*, see [what's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)). `numpy.array` needs a sequence so the `len` can be determined and the appropriate amount of memory reserved; it won't consume an iterator. For example, the `range` object, which *does* support most sequence operations, *can* be passed directly;

```
seq = np.array(range(5))
print(seq)
# prints: [0 1 2 3 4]
```

To restore the previous behaviour, as you're aware, you can explicitly convert the `map` object back to a sequence (e.g. list or tuple):

```
seq = np.array(list(seq))  # should probably change the name!
```

However, as [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) puts it:

> a quick fix is to wrap `map()` in `list()`, e.g. `list(map(...))`, but a better fix is often to use a list comprehension (especially when the original code uses `lambda`)

So another option would be:

```
seq = [f(x) for x in range(5)]
```

or just:

```
seq = [x**2 for x in range(5)]
```

Alternatively, actually use `numpy` from the start:

```
import numpy as np    
arr = np.arange(5)
arr **= 2
print(arr)
# prints [ 0  1  4  9 16] in 2.x and 3.x
```

Comment: @btel no, `np.array` won't consume the iterator. You need the full list up-front so the appropriate memory can be reserved.