# Convert map object into numpy ndarray in python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

The following code works well in python2, but after migration to python3, it does not work. 
How do I change this code in python3?

```
for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
    user_id, item_id = idx 
    feature_seq = np.array(map(lambda x: user_id, item_id))  
    X[i, :len(item_id), :] = feature_seq  # ---- error here ----
```

error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'
```

Thank you.

Comment: In PY3, `map` is like a generator, you need to wrap it in `list()` to produce a list that `np.array` can use: e.g. `np.array(list(map(...)))`.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooo much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert map object to numpy array in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524378/convert-map-object-to-numpy-array-in-python-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PY3, `map` is like a generator.  You need to wrap it in `list()` to produce a list that `np.array` can use: e.g.

```
 np.array(list(map(...)))
```

Answer (score 5):

In python3, Map returns a iterator, not a list.
You can also try [numpy.fromiter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) to get an array from a map obj，only for 1-D data.

Example:

```
a=map(lambda x:x,range(10))
b=np.fromiter(a,dtype=np.int)
b
```

Ouput:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

For `multidimensional arrays`, refer to [Reconcile np.fromiter and multidimensional arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018470/reconcile-np-fromiter-and-multidimensional-arrays-in-python)